# How to connect MS SQL dynamically with postgreSQl data base

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore, postgresql-9.2, database-backups

I am very new in PostgreSQL database. I am currently using MS SQL server 2008. Now i need the whole data in postgreSQL, I have installed postgreSQL in my server. Kindly tell me the procedure to connect with PostgreSQl. If there is no option, kindly tell me whether we can take back up of MS SQl and restore it in postgreSQl

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you need an ETL tool to transfer the data from one to the other or you have to export in a neutral format, like .csv, and import into the other using built in tools.

I'd opt for the first one.